# Are new vectors created even if the old ones aren't used anymore?

Tags: haskell, vector, mutable

This question is about the `Data.Vector` package.

Given the fact that I'll never use the old value of a certain cell once the cell is updated. Will the update operation always create a new vector, reflecting the update, or will it be done as an in-place update ?

Note: I know about `Data.Vector.Mutable`

Comment: How is it going to know that's valid?

Comment: Well the compiler can see the old vector is not used anywhere.

Comment: Then it's not a feature of the data structure but a rather low-level compiler optimization.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, but something even better can happen.

Data.Vector is built using ["stream fusion"](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/2192). This means that if the sequence of operations that you are performing to build up and then tear down the vector can be fused away, **then the Vector itself will never even be constructed** and your code will turn into an optimized loop.

Fusion works by turning code that would build vectors into code that builds up and tears down streams and then puts the streams into a form that the compiler can see to perform optimizations.

So code that looks like

```
foo :: Int
foo = sum as
   where as, bs, cs, ds, es :: Vector Int
         as = map (*100) bs 
         bs = take 10 cs
         cs = zipWith (+) (generate 1000 id) ds
         ds = cons 1 $ cons 3 $ map (+2) es 
         es = replicate 24000 0
```

despite appearing to build up and tear down quite a few very large vectors can fuse all the way down to an inner loop that only calculates and adds 10 numbers.

Doing what you proposed is tricky, because it requires that you know that no references to a term exist anywhere else, which imposes a cost on any attempt to copy a reference into an environment. Moreover, it interacts rather poorly with laziness. You need to attach little affine addenda to the thunk you conspicuously didn't evaluate yet. But to do this in a multithreaded environment is scarily race prone and hard to get right.

Comment: That's a great answer !
I don't get what's special about stream fusion though. Shouldn't this be the case by default using lazy evaluation. I mean in the example you gave if we were dealing with lists shouldn't it also be a single loop which adds 10 numbers ?

Comment: @brence: If your algorithm has a suitable structure, laziness can certainly get you constant space, but you'll still be hopping between thunks as the structure is forced. Fusion optimizations are about cutting out indirections and sticking it all together. My impression is that, compared to the naive lazy form, the fused version is "only" improved by significant constant factors, not an improvement in overall resource complexity.

Comment: If the vector is never constructed what is the advantage of it rather than using a fusion-streaming list (and, as a sidenote, when is GHC going to support that in the default list implementation? I think the main problem was the implementation of concat...)

Comment: monadic: the main issue is that fusion streaming on lists is just not currently supplied by ghc. Also some parts of your code wont fuse. So its nice to have those get stored in a nice compact representation like Data.Vector.Unboxed when you are forced to do things like look up a lot of indices. The Data.Vector approach gives you both nice properties when the data is 'at rest' and when it is in in motion via streaming without requiring conscious consideration on behalf of the user.

Comment: @camccann: not only would you be hopping between thinks, but Vector itself when materialized is basically a (bunch of) flat arrays of memory. In the example I gave above, a couple of those entries had 1000+ entries that this way never got created.

Comment: @Edward Kmett: Well, I was assuming that the naive lazy version would be done with lists instead. Of course, even handwaving lazy lists vs. stream fusion, the nicer properties of `Vector` when you actually want the whole thing around are pretty persuasive, so it's largely moot.

Comment: when the reference is to an argument of an internal function, and it is updated [inside a tail call](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers#Accumulating_Array), the uniqueness of reference is readily evident w/out any additional cost, though: `fun = g where g a | ... = ...; g a = g (a// ...)`. Such update should be done destructively, it seems.

Comment: @WillNess: Keep in mind vector is a library, not part of the compiler, so inspecting uniqueness of reference are outside of its purview. That said, what you ask for may happen given the machinery for `Data.Vector.New` and the way that avoids freeze/thaw cycles. It'd depend on the particulars of your ...'s and whether the code was amenable to a worker-wrapper transform.

Answer (score 2):

Well, how exactly should the compiler see that "the old vector is not used anywhere"? Say we have a function that changes a vector:

```
changeIt :: Vector Int -> Int -> Vector Int
changeIt vec n = vec // [(0,n)]
```

Just from this definition, the compiler cannot assume that `vec` represents the only reference to the vector in question. We would have to annotate the function so it can only be used in this way - which Haskell doesn't support (but Clean does, as far as I know).

So what *can* we do in Haskell? Let us say we have another silly function:

```
changeItTwice vec n = changeIt (changeIt vec n) (n+1)
```

Now GHC could inline `changeIt`, and indeed "see" that no reference to the intermediate structure escapes. But typically, you would use this information to *not* produce that intermediate data structure, instead directly generating the end result!

This is a pretty common optimization (for lists, there is fusion, for example) - and I think it plays pretty much exactly the role you have in mind: Limiting the number of times a data structure needs to be copied. Whether or not this approach is more flexible than in-place-updates is up for debate, but you can definitely recover a lot of performance  *without* having to break abstraction by annotating uniqueness properties.

(However, I think that `Vector` currently does not, in fact, perform this specific optimization. Might need a few more optimizer rules...)

Comment: From the `vector` package description: "An efficient implementation of Int-indexed arrays (both mutable and immutable), with a powerful loop fusion optimization framework." You may have it backwards, because in many cases I don't think GHC can reliably fuse lists.

Comment: exactly: re: `changeItTwice` -- or *`n`* times: cf. [this](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers#Accumulating_Array), updating an array inside a recursive tail call of an internal function, e.g.: `fun = g where g a b c | ... = ... ; g a b c = g (a // ...) b' c'`. surely it can be done destructively here! :)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO this is certainly impossible as the GHC garbage collector may go havoc if you randomly change an object (even if it is not used anymore). That is because the object may be moved into an older generation and mutation could introduce pointers to a younger generation. If now the younger generation gets garbage collected, the object may move and thus the pointer may become invalid.

AFAIK, all mutable objects in Haskell are located on a special heap that is treated differently by the GC, so that such problems can't occur.

Comment: You can use unsafeThaw and unsafeFreeze to simulate this, can't you? Then I would say that it wouldn't throw the GC off according to the docs...

Comment: @nomadic I am not sure, but IIRC those operations just coerce the vector without changing the place of allocation.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. `Data.Vector` uses [stream fusion](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~dons/papers/stream-fusion.pdf), so depending on your use the vector may not be created at all and the program may compile to an efficient constant space loop.

This mostly applies to operations that transform the entire vector rather than just updating a single cell, though.